# Cannot read video output

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, opencv3.0

I am using the example for background subtraction. It works well but the video output is unreadable. My video is in **gray** so that might be the reason why I get that problem. I couldn't find much information how to work with *VideoWriter_fourcc* & *VideoWriter* different parameters. I know that the video is 256x320 uint8.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

#MOG2 Backgroundsubstrator
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('videotest.avi')

fgbg = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2()
##
# Define the codec and create VideoWriter object
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',fourcc, 20.0, (256,320))
##
while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    fgmask = fgbg.apply(frame)  

    if ret==True:
        cv2.imshow('frame',fgmask)
        out.write(fgmask)
        k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
        if k == 27:
            break
    else:
        break 

cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using:

```
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
```

Works if you write the video as is. In this case, I am trying to write the video with a background subtraction. The fix is:

```
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIB ')
```

Note: Do not forget the space after DIB. I am using Python 3.5 & OpenCV3.1